# Coding Stack with Horizontal scroll Bar on my trial page

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to blot out the horizontal scroll bar from my site.Below I have post two pictures which display that the problem appears in two div elements.
[this picture display the problematic div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xytlC.png)

but I haven't this two lines of code 
`.row { margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px; }`
in my CSS file.
This refers to file with name grid-framework.less.
Could you anyone help me to solve this bug?
Thanks.

Here is the code of my CSS file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: OpenSans Bold;
src: url('OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}

header .navbar-default {
background: url("/diary/pictures/home-banner-background.jpg") no-repeat    center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
max-width: 100%;
height: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-left img {
max-width: 200px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 25px;
}


/* search and date picker*/
.date {
margin-top: 5px;
}

.row .col-lg-2 {
padding: 4px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 25px;
}

.col-lg-2 b {
font-size: 16px;
}

.glyphicon-calendar {
padding: 4px;
margin-top: 1px;
}

.search {
padding: 4px;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-right: -5px;
position: relative;
}

.search span {
padding: 4px;
}

/* body */

.body-page {
background: #C6C6C6;
max-width: 100%;
height: 865px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.table-responsive {
max-width: 90%;
float: right;
padding-right: 200px;
margin-right: 50px;
/*
padding-right: 200px;*/
}

th > a {
border-radius: 2px;
}

tbody tr:last-child a {
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 3px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: OpenSans;
}

tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
padding-left: 2px;
font-family: OpenSans;
}

tbody tr:nth-last-child(3) a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #f92b2b;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 3px 4px;
}

#table_3 > tbody tr {
font-family: OpenSans;
}

#table_2 > tbody tr {
font-family: OpenSans;
}

.table {
font-family: OpenSans;
}

.glyphicon-remove {
margin-left: 8px;
}

#access_1 {
padding-left: 20px;
max-width: 20%;
float: left;
}

#table_2 {
height: 240px;
width: 240px;
}

#table_3 {
margin-top: 20px;
height: 240px;
width: 240px;
}

/*footer*/

footer {
background-color: #3F3C3C;
max-width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}

footer .report {
width: 300px;
float: right;
padding-top: 18px;
}

footer .report a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
margin-right: 5px;
}
footer a:hover {
cursor: pointer;
color: #f9a42b;
}
```

Comment: May we see some HTML or a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?.

Comment: Here you could see the HTML and JS code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/panaras/7pv0c47u/1/). In the CSS chapter I have add the CSS code again and between  comments node the code of datepicker.less file.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the issue, but why have you got `margin-left: 25px;` on `.row .col-lg-2`? IIRC this is likely the culprit.

Comment: @Ryan Gee No unfortunately the `.row.col-lg-2 margin-left:25px;` not create the problem.The picture which I upload with link in my first post "the picture display the problematic div", presents that the div class `.row` have two margins `.row { margin-left:-15px; margin-right:-15px; }` which I have not put in my code. I can't understand how this line created and in which file I can  founded and deleted. Please check in my firts paragraph the picture I have post.

Comment: I can't see those margins in the jsfiddle you posted, so it's very difficult for me to debug further I'm afraid!